# How to check the related objects status from detail view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Here I want to check whether the question's answers are already voted by the current user or not .

For this I tried like this but I think this will not work.

I want to do this for some purposes in the template like one is `{% if a_voted %}Voted{% else %}Vote{% endif %}`.

i did it for question but got stuck while doing for the answers.

models

```
  class Answer(models.Model):
        question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
        ans = models.TextField()
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='user_answers')
    
    class AnswerVote(models.Model):
        answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answer_votes')
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_votes_ans')
```

views

```
class DetailQuestionView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=kwargs['pk'])
        q_voted = question.question_votes.filter(user=request.user, question=question).exists()
        answers = question.answers.all()
        a_voted = [True if answer.answer_votes.filter(user=request.user, answer=answer).exists() else False for answer in answers]
        context = {
            'question': question,
            'q_voted': q_voted,
            'a_voted': a_voted,
        }
```

template

```
{% for answer in question.answers.all %}
    <p>{{answer.ans}}</p>
     <form action="{% url 'qa:vote_ans' answer.pk %}" method="post" id="a-vote-form ">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit"
     class="{% if a_voted %}btn btn-danger disabled{% else %} btn btn-success{% endif %}">
     {% if a_voted %}Voted{% else %}Vote{% endif %}</button>
      </form>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create `a_voted_list` since you can access the list of answers voted by the user via `user.answervote_set.all()`

```
{% if answer in request.user.answervote_set.all %}Voted{% else %}Vote{% endif %}
```